# Node js soap empty result with base64 string

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js, web-services, soap

I am trying to send a file(with a size of 64Kb) in base64 format to my .Net web service in node js using soap, but the result is empty. I don't know if it is because of the size of the base64 string, because when I send this string empty it responded normally.

```
file = req.file;
if(file){
  file64 = base64_encode('public/assets/uploads/' + file.filename);
}

var args = {file: file64};
soapClient.uploadFile(args, function(err, result) {   
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      var response = JSON.parse(result.uploadFileResult);
      if(!response.response){
        console.log(response.message);
      }else{
        //Handlers
      }
    }
   });
```

When I print the result in console it shows: {}

Comment: Try a file size somewhere between. Maybe you have to change some (default) configuration settings (MaxRequestLength for example)